# Getting 500 error for https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting a 500 error while invoking https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile endpoint from
Graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). When I check the network tab, I can see the error response as below. Any idea why? I tried resetting my birthdate multiple times from account.microsoft.com but that is still not fixing the timestamp & lastModifiedBy issue

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('...')/profile/$entity","id":"profileId","addresses@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('...')/profile/addresses","addresses":[],"anniversaries@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('...')/profile/anniversaries","anniversaries":[{"type":"birthday","date":"...","allowedAudiences":"me","createdDateTime":"2020-06-30T21:52:30.364606Z","inference":null,"lastModifiedDateTime":"2020-06-30T21:52:30.364606Z"{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "The property 'lastModifiedBy[Nullable=False]' of type 'microsoft.graph.identitySet' has a null value, which is not allowed.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-30T22:15:16",
      "request-id": "b9402c6b-297d-4190-a829-8297dae69d9d"
    }
  }
}{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'anniversaries[0].lastModifiedDateTime', line 1, position 587.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-30T22:15:16",
      "request-id": "b9402c6b-297d-4190-a829-8297dae69d9d"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error.

Comment: I am using Nuget Microsoft.Graph.Beta version 0.19.0-preview in C#